# Spring SOAP WS: WssSoapFaultException implementing SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler

Tags: java, soap, spring-ws

I'm following a course to review some Spring concepts and I'm trying to implement a SOAP WS with simple password validation security.

My bean configuration is like the following

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WsdlConfigService extends WsConfigurerAdapter {

    // Other beans...
    
    @Bean
    public XwsSecurityInterceptor requestInterceptor() {
        XwsSecurityInterceptor interceptor = new XwsSecurityInterceptor();
        interceptor.setCallbackHandler(callbackHandler());
        interceptor.setPolicyConfiguration(new ClassPathResource("securityPolicy.xml"));
        return interceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler callbackHandler() { 
        SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler handler = new SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler();
        handler.setUsersMap(Collections.singletonMap("admin", "password"));
        return handler;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
        interceptors.add(requestInterceptor());
    }
}
```

and the `securityPolicy.xml` configuration is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xwss:SecurityConfiguration xmlns:xwss="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/xwss/config">
    <xwss:RequireUsernameToken passwordDigestRequired="false" nonceRequired="false" />
</xwss:SecurityConfiguration>
```

When I try to test the endpoint security (I'm using Wizdler Chrome extension) I'm getting an unexpected error:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en">com.sun.xml.wss.impl.WssSoapFaultException: javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException; nested exception is com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: com.sun.xml.wss.impl.WssSoapFaultException: javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException</faultstring>
        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

In the Wizdler interface I'm using WSSE PasswordText Authentication because of the `SimplePassWrodValidationCallbackHandler` bean.

What am I doing wrong here? I tried with Spring Boot versions 2.5.1 (latest at the time of this writing) and 2.4.5 (the one used in the course)

If you need more details on this issue please let me know. Thanks in advance for your answers/comments.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the error: I was using an incorrect `javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler` implementation: I was using `org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.callback.SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler` but the correct one is `org.springframework.ws.soap.security.xwss.callback.SimplePasswordValidationCallbackHandler`.

Both implementations comes from the Spring Framework and should do the same (according to the documentation) but for some reason the first one is not supported. If someone has more detailed information, please let me know.

Comment: XWSS is the Sun proprietary implementation, which has not been updated since 2018 and has a lot of security vulnerabilities.  WSS4J is the Apache open-source version which is actively supported.  It's best to use WSS4J, but both will work.